# Merge audio background video with original video by ffmeg

Tags: audio, video, merge, background

***Use case:***
I have one original video with original sound. Call it (A)
I have one background video with edited sound. Background video is shorter than original video.Call it (B)
I already merge A with B done (audio of B muted).
Now I want to merge A with B but still keep audio of B with lower volume about 15%.
How can I do with FFmpeg?
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge using audio filter
Check example below

```
ffmpeg -i "F:/A.mp4" -i "F:/B.mp4" -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=x=100:y=100[ABVideo];[1:a]volume=0.15[a];[0:a]volume=0.9[b];[a][b]amix=inputs=2:duration=longest[ABAudio]" -map [ABVideo] -map [ABAudio] f:/AB.mp4
```

Explained

```
-i F:/A.mp4
```

First input

```
-i F:/B.mp4
```

Second video file with audio for which you want 15%

```
[0:v][1:v]overlay=x=100:y=100[ABVideo]
```

This is for the sake of overlay as you have mentioned merge I did not completely understand by the word merge so i thought overlay (Overlay second video on first video at x = 100 and y = 100

Here is the code in which you are interested

```
[1:a]volume=0.15[a];[0:a]volume=0.9[b];
```

Second input file audio change the volume to 15% and first input file audio change it to 90% ( You can change )

```
[a][b]amix=inputs=2:duration=longest[ABAudio]
```

Combine two audio stream named a and b into [ABAudio]

```
 -map [ABVideo] -map [ABAudio]
```

Map the streams for video and audio

Comment: Exactly I did not merge, just overlay at first. I will try your guide. Thanks and best of the best for you.

Comment: Here is code that I am using. Can you help me edit it.

Comment: DO ffmpeg -y -i A.mp4 -i "Thanhcaro.png" -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=734:524[v]; movie=B.mp4:loop=999,setpts=N/(FRAME_RATE*TB), scale=1280:720 [bg]; [bg][v]overlay=shortest=1:x=545:y=196 [v1]; [v1][1:v]overlay=0:0;[0:a]volume=10,lowpass=f=500,highpass=f=1500,bass=g=-30,equalizer=f=10.5:width_type=o:width=1:g=-30" -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 -g 60 -b:v 2500k -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -preset ultrafast output.mp4

Comment: I do as your guide and set music volume of B ok but audio of B does not loop as length of full Video.

Comment: Here is my code. Pls help me with more simple code. Thank you. DO ffmpeg -y -i A.mp4 -i B.mp4 -i thanhcaro.png -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=770:550,setpts=PTS/1.1[v]; movie=B.mp4:loop=999,setpts=N/(FRAME_RATE*TB), scale=1280:720 [bg]; [bg][v]overlay=shortest=1:x=545:y=196[v1];[V1][2:v]overlay=0:0[ABvideo];[1:a]volume=0.15[a1];[0:a]atempo=1.1,volume=0.9[a2];[a1][a2]amix=inputs=2:duration=longest[ABaudio]" -map [ABVideo] -map [ABAudio] -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 -g 60 -b:v 2500k -acodec libmp3lame -ar 44100 -preset ultrafast output.mp4"

Comment: I also have problem with this command, render short A video ok but I got problem when render long A video. Example for 31 minutes A video, command did not stop and CPU take over load :((.